# Generating minimal-looking graph in pgf plots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to generate simple-looking plots such as this one:

[image]

I've tried the following:

```
\usepgflibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfplotsset{my style/.append style={axis x line=middle, axis y line=
middle, xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, axis equal }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[my style, xticklabels={},extra x ticks ={1} ,yticklabels=none,extra x tick style={xticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}]
    \addplot[domain=-1:2, red, thick] {x*ln(x)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to remove ticks, but keep the tick at 'x=1'. Also, how can I make this function look smoother?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `xtick={1}`, `ytick=\empty` to suppress the ticks, except for x=1, and `samples=<number>` to get a smoother path; in your example code there's no need to use `extra x tick style={xticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}`. Since you are using a logarithm, it's best to set the domain for non negative values (such as `domain=0.0001:2`, although `domain=0:2` won't cause problems either in this concrete case) and use `xmin` to extend the x-axis to negative values:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgflibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfplotsset{my style/.append style={axis x line=middle, axis y line=
middle, xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, axis equal }}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[my style, xtick={1},ytick=\empty,samples=100,xmin=-1]
    \addplot[domain=0.0001:2, red, thick] {x*ln(x)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

As [`Heiko Oberdiek suggests`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267227/generating-minimal-looking-graph-in-pgf-plots/267234?noredirect=1#comment640883_267234) one could also use `domain=0:2` and a conditional test on the function definition to avoid problems (though, in this concrete case there aren't) with the value at zero:

```
\begin{axis}[my style, xtick={1},ytick=\empty,samples=100,xmin=-1]
\addplot[domain=0:2, red, thick] {x == 0 ? 0 : x*ln(x)};
\end{axis}
```

Comment: thanks! Why does it get rid of stuff on the negative x axis though? I'd prefer it to show for x=-1 at least?

Comment: @dimebucker91 You're welcome! Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Suggestion for the definition gap: `domain=0:2` with function `x == 0 ? 0 : x*ln(x)`.